# Installing Full Tex Search to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation, full-text-search

I installed sql server 2008 R2 successfully, then realised I need to get Full Text Search. So I downloaded the "[Advanced Services Installation Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25174)", but when I run it there is no option in the "Feature Selection" part for Full Text Search. Please don't tell me I hav to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to give me the feature as an option by just installing another instance of the server (now running side by side my original) - What a Schlepp!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the previous instance you installed so as to upgrade it?If no try to select the instance you previously installed.